# Calculate min and max with groupby while calculating average

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame similar to this:

```
day         |   points     |    tries    |        game
monday      |      3.4     |      2      |      sudoku
monday      |      3       |      1      |      sudoku
monday      |      2.1     |      4      |      tetris
monday      |      2.7     |      3      |      tetris
tuesday     |      1.1     |      2      |      sudoku
wednesday   |      0       |      2      |      sudoku
tuesday     |      3.3     |      2      |      tetris
```

I am trying to first group by Games and inside every different "game", group by "day" and calculate which is the max and min (but for each "day" individually and excluding 0 points - so >0.001 for example). But this min and max have to be calculated from the average of that day.

So for example, for game "sudoku", first "monday" would have an average of (3.4/2), second monday an average of 3/1, tuesday would have 1.1/2 as average and wednesday an average of 0/2 but as stated before 0 points would be excluded.

So for sudoku the result should be something similar to:

```
sudoku      |average_points|    tries    |        day
min         |     0.55     |      2      |      tuesday
max         |      3       |      1      |      monday
```

and it should show this kind of table for every "game".

I have been reading about groupby but I don't find the day to do all this and at the same time calculate average_points for each group.

Also, how would we have to do to take for example on calculation rows where number of tries is bigger than 10 for example.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is for trying to analyze more easily some csv files. I have been able to open the data, read it and do some simple groupby commands but this multiple selection and average calculation is driving me crazy.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add final DataFrame to question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
#filter out 0 points
df = df[df['points'].ne(0)]
#create average column  
df = df.assign(average_points = df['points'].div(df['tries']))
#grouping object and processing column of averages
g = df.groupby('game')['average_points']
#join together rows by minimal and maximal averages with keys for get min, max to column
df = (pd.concat([df.loc[g.idxmin()], 
                 df.loc[g.idxmax()]], keys=('min','max'))
       .sort_values('game')
       .reset_index(level=0)
       .rename(columns={'level_0':'type'}))
print (df)
  type      day  points  tries    game  average_points
4  min  tuesday     1.1      2  sudoku           0.550
1  max   monday     3.0      1  sudoku           3.000
2  min   monday     2.1      4  tetris           0.525
6  max  tuesday     3.3      2  tetris           1.650
```

Comment: That works perfectly, really thank you very much. I have been fighting with this all morning. Only thing to add, how could I do to filter for example and use only rows where tries are lets say greater than 3. So that I make sure that averages are statistically significant.

Comment: To be honest I don't where to put that exactly. I am also not sure it's what I am trying to say. Just to be sure, on my original data frame, if we say it has to use rows where tries are greater than 3, it would only have to calculate min and max with the row monday      |      2.1     |      4      |      tetris

Comment: @Gabriel - yes, then it is different, need `df = df[df['tries'] > 3]` before my solution

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael has given you an elegant pure `pandas` solution. I took your output rather literally:

```
# Make the 'average' column.
df['average_points'] = df.points / df.tries

# Eliminate zeros.
df = df[df.average_points > 0]

# Print the tables.
for game, group in df.groupby('game'):
    print(f'{game:<10s}|average_points|{"tries":^10s}|{"day":>10s}')

    minn = group.loc[group.average_points.idxmin()]
    print(f'{"min":<10s}|{minn.average_points:^14.2f}|{minn.tries:^10d}|{minn.day:>10s}')

    maxx = group.loc[group.average_points.idxmax()]
    print(f'{"max":<10s}|{maxx.average_points:^14.2f}|{maxx.tries:^10d}|{maxx.day:>10s}')

    print()
```

I notice that we get different results, so I guess one of us misunderstood the stats you want.

Comment: I am going to try both codes. I think the difference is you added the minimum 10 tries to calculate the result.